# Find the basis for $ker(T)$ where $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \ \ \ (x,y,z) \to (y,y,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the basis for $ker(T)$ where $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \ \ \ (x,y,z) \to (y,y,y)$ 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1& 0\\ 
0 & 1& 0\\ 
0 & 1& 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$is reduced to$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1& 0\\ 
0 & 0& 0\\ 
0 & 0& 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \implies y=0 $$
$$\therefore ker(T)=(x,0,z) = x(1,0,0)+z(0,0,1) \\
\therefore basis(ker(T)= \{ (1 \ 0 \ 0),(0 \ 0 \ 1) \}$$

Is this right?

Comment: $T:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right,$$K = \ker{T} = \{(a,0,b)| a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

A basis for $K$ is then

$$\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\}$$

Since given $(a,0,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$(a,0,b) = a\cdot(1,0,0)+b\cdot(0,0,1)$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the matrix representation. T will map a vector to $(0,0,0)$ iff its $y$-component is zero. So your basis is the correct one.